# What is the component used in the point of sale of odoo erp

Tags: odoo-8, point-of-sale

I'm currently developing an application (Point of Sale) winforms C #; I want to know what is the component used (circled in picture) and his equivalent in c#.
[component used by the ERP Odoo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zshBQ.png)

Comment: What do you mean with component? Could you be more specific? What do you need?

Comment: i need to get the same Interface in c# winforms , i tried to get the same look by C1truedbgrid or gridview by i could'nt have the same look.
is their a tool that give me the same look to the picture?

Comment: I strongly recommend you Wappalyzer (Chromium extension) to check what tools and frameworks are used by Odoo.

Comment: ok thanks for your answer